# CasperJS: Parsing page with non-UTF8 encoding

Tags: encoding, utf-8, casperjs

I am trying to retrieve the some text from a website that uses SHIFT_JIS encoding.
I the code below displays text correctly for pages that uses utf8, but as the output from the below code illustrates, there are problems when the encoding differs.
If someone could point to a work around, i would be very grateful

The output returned looks like; "¥¨¥ì¥¯¥È¥í¥Ë¥¯¥¹"

But should look like; "第28回いきいき大田写真コンクール作品募集"

```
/*=================================================*/
var casper = require("casper").create({
verbose: true,
logLevel: "debug"
});

function getMultiTextList(cssSelector) {
var query = document.querySelectorAll(cssSelector);
return Array.prototype.map.call(query, function (element) {
return element.innerText;
});
}

var testurl = "https://www.city.ota.tokyo.jp/";
var testcss = "#mainback > div.main.clearfix > div.main-c > div.oshirese.clearfix > ul > li:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(2) > a"
casper.start();

casper.thenOpen(testurl, function() {

this.save()
titleList = this.evaluate(getMultiTextList,testcss);

for (var i = 0; i < titleList.length; i++)
{
this.echo(titleList[i])
}
});

casper.run(function() {
this.exit();
});
```

Comment: You mean that's the output on the console. Have you tried piping the output into a file and looking at it in a capable file viewer?

Comment: I just tried this by adding `fs.write(fileName, titleList[i] + ",", 'a');`, but the output is still garbled, returning `‘æ11‰ñŠ—“c“sŽs‚Ã‚­‚è„i‰ï‹c‚ðŠJÃ‚µ‚Ü‚·,`

Comment: Have you tried setting the output encoding? `casperjs --output-encoding=SHIFT_JIS script.js`

Comment: No luck with this either - same result as the last comment.

Answer (score 3):

Try to run the script with the output encoding command line parameter:

```
casperjs --output-encoding=cp866 [params] [filename]
```